# Pointing a domain to ip address

Tags: hosting, self-hosting

I am working on a project, where I have a domain `xyz.com`, I have been requested that a subdomain example `abc.xyz.com` should point to website which has ipaddress
example `http://199.152.57.120/client/` and when a visitor browse `abc.xyz.com` it should open the website hosted on `http://199.152.57.120/client/` but by hidding this ip address the visitor should always see `abc.xyz.com`.

I also need to host another website to `xyz.com`
domain which is registered with *x* company and webhosting is taken for  *z* company both different.
It is something similar to Reseller business  where Reseller company assign a website to their client on their  custom domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can make A record in your DNS Server that IP address 199.152.57.120 pointing to abc.xyz.com

and then make same configuration in your web hosting that nginx/httpd virtual host point to directory /Some/Directory/client

you can read this for nginx https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/how-to-configure-nginx

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done in domain provider DNS zone. Just add A record where you will provide subdomain ex: abc.xyz.com and connect to adress ex: 1.2.3.4 How to do that in your domain provider, just check help pages for DNS records.
Alternatively you can install proxy software like NGINX and make subdomain redirect.

Example setting:
[image]

Comment: i already added a record and its perfectly pointing to the ip address but the address in url changes to the ip address i dont want to the ip address it should remain ex abc.xyz.com

Comment: maybe if you are using apache on your target machine you miss the Virtual host entry. That's why it reverts back to ip address. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767624/ip-address-is-shown-in-address-bar-instead-of-domain

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['userid'] sfda$_SESSION['userid'] sddcdcadc$_SESSION['userid']$_SESSION['userid'] sfda$_SESSION['userid'] sddcdcadc$_SESSION['userid']
```